# Why i have this 2 different value of DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I am using `Pcap.Net` to find my `Pcap File Packet` `Timestamp`.
With `Pcap.Net` `TimeStamp` is one of the `Packet` properties.
So this is my `Packet`  `TimeStamp`:

```
packet.Timestamp    {7/5/2012 2:20:20 PM}
```

I have another calss that opens another format of `Wiresahrk` and with this class `Packet` properties is contains only `Seconds` and `Microseconds` (int vale).
So with this calss the same Packet time stamp looks different and i think this is because my conversion is wrong.
This is what i have try:

```
MyPacket myPacket;

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(myPacket.Seconds).AddTicks(myPacket.Microseconds * 10);
```

So after build this Packet with `Pcap.net` this is how `Packet` `TimeStamp` look like:

```
packet.Timestamp    {7/5/2012 11:20:20 AM}
```

So my question is why there is a different of several hours between them both ?

- **Edit**

I have another class that open another `Wiresahrk` format and in this case `Packet` `TimeStamp` here is type of `long` so i will glad for help also with this.

Comment: Perhaps one is in UTC time and one is in local time. Can you find any info about that in the wireshark spec or the pcap spec? What timezone are you in?

Comment: please provide the Seconds and Microseconds values.

Comment: Second 20, Millisecond 581

Comment: I guess, your time zone might be (UTC - 03.00)